False proof $(Av)^T=v^TA.$
Given $u^Tv = u\cdot v=v\cdot u=v^Tu,$
I tried to prove the well-known $(Av)^T=v^TA^T$ so I did the following
$$(Av)^Tv=v^T(Av)=(v^TA)v$$
and got $(Av)^T=v^TA$ instead.
Can someone explain what went wrong?

You got $(Av)^Tv=(v^TA)v$, but you can't cancel $v$ from the right side to get $(Av)^T=v^TA$.

Provided that $A$ is a square matrix and $v$ has compatible dimensions to write $Av$ in the first place,
$$ v^T A v = v^T A^T v. $$
But this is true in general only because it's $v$ (in normal or transposed orientation) on each side of each matrix.
It doesn't work in general with an arbitrary matrix and two arbitrary vectors, even if we stipulate that the matrix must be square.
That's why we cannot conclude $v^T A = v^T A^T$.
Likewise with your "proof", from
$(Av)^Tv=(v^TA)v$ you cannot conclude that $(Av)^T=v^TA$.
Now, if you can show that $(Av)^Tu=(v^TA)u$ for every vector $u$ of suitable dimensions, then you could conclude that $(Av)^T=v^TA$.
But you can't do that, because it's not true in general.

I would look carefully at the size of $A$ and $v$. If $A$ is $m\times n$ and $v$ is $n\times 1$ so that $Av$ is defined and $m\times 1$, then $(Av)^T$ is $1\times m$, so $(Av)^T v$ is undefined as it is a $1\times m$ times a $n\times 1$, and $m\ne n$ in general.

Even if $A$ is $n\times n$ the "proof" is still invalid.

The proof can easily be shown to be wrong by taking an arbitrary example.
More formally, I am assuming that we stuck to the convention of a matrix being represented by capital letters and a vector by common letters. I am also assuming that the proof is intended to apply in general, i.e., to all appropriately sized matrices and vectors. It certainly applies in the trivial case of $A$ and $v$ being scalars (1 $\times$ 1 matrices).
There are several missteps in the solution.
The first results from the incorrect assumption that the inner product operation between two vectors $u$ and $v$ can be extended to matrix/vector multiplication. Since the inner product between two vectors results in a scalar then it is always the case that $v^Tu=u^T v$. This does not apply in general to matrix/vector multiplication.
This incorrect assumption is then applied to the intermediate step to get the incorrect result "$(Av)^Tv= v^T (Av)$".  This should read $(Av)^Tv= v^T (A^T v)$.
The other misstep is in the last step of the proposed proof where there is a cancellation of the $v$ vector on either side of the equation to get the target result. Here the vector is being treated as a scalar - a cardinal sin in linear algebra.
